# chart.js line chart and "correct" spacing between points? (i.e. horizontal position based on percent of width, not fixed)

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

Suppose we have the following x-axis values on a chart.js (line) chart: `[0,1.9,2,3,4,5]`.

chart.js seems to chart this with the space between 0 and 1.9 being the same as the space between 1.9 and 2?

Is there a simple way to change the behavior (I assume manually setting the tick marks/grid lines would fix this, but perhaps there is an even simpler way?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <Title> Chart </Title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p> Ex chart go</p>
        <div>
            <canvas id = "myChart"></canvas>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
        <script>
            const ctx = document.getElementById(`myChart`);
            const xval = [0,1.9,2,3,4,5];
            const yval = [10,8,6,4,2,0]
            const toPlot = {
                labels:xval,
                datasets: [{
                    label: "Ex chart",
                    data: yval,
                    fill: false
                }]
            };
            let myChart= new Chart(ctx, {
                type: `line`,
                data: toPlot,
                options: {

                }
            })
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Edit: Let me try to restate my question**

- In the example above the horizontal values go from 0 to 5.
- Suppose the chart has a width of 100px
- since horizontal value of 2 is 2/5 of the total horizontal range, it should be (2/5)*100px from the start of the horizontal axis
- similarly, since 1.9 is 1.9/5 of the total horizontal range, it should be (1.9/5)*100px from the start of the horizontal axis
- **however, chart.js seems to be spacing all horizontal points evenly?**

Edit 2: Graphics to show what I am asking.

- I want gridlines as in the first picture: they are equally space (a fixed number of pixels of width is a fixed difference between gridlines). However, chart.js seems to do as in the second picture
- look at how the spacing between the red points is not even in the first picture (what I want), as compared to the second picture (chart.js)

[image: what i want picture]
[image: chart.js picture]

Comment: I don't think that you can achieve that from config.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou Thanks. I have been looking and I think using a scatter instead of a `line` with the `showLine:True`  or something like that might work. I'll figure it out.

Comment: I think you can do it with canvasjs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default scale type for the X axis is `category` this takes all labels and makes it a datapoint, if you change the scale type to `linear` you will get what you want.

Example:

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById(`myChart`);
  const xval = [0, 1.9, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  const yval = [10, 8, 6, 4, 2, 0]
  const toPlot = {
    labels: xval,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Ex chart",
      data: yval,
      fill: false
    }]
  };
  let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: `line`,
    data: toPlot,
    options: {
      scales: {
        x: {
          type: 'linear',
          ticks: {
            stepSize: 1 // remove this line to get autoscalling 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

Comment: ahhhhhhhhh, I tried this but typed `linear` not as a string... thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it with a scatter plot, and setting `showLine: True`

(maybe some other random stuff thrown in there that does nothing useful, sorry. been messing with the code)

(note: data needs to be in a different format for scatter)

```html
<div>
  <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<script>
  const ctx = document.getElementById(`myChart`);
  // const xval = [0,1.9,2,3,4,5];
  // const yval = [10,8,6,4,2,0]
  const scatterData = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 10
  }, {
    x: 1.9,
    y: 8
  }, {
    x: 2,
    y: 6
  }, {
    x: 3,
    y: 4
  }, {
    x: 4,
    y: 2
  }, {
    x: 5,
    y: 0
  }]
  const toPlot = {
    // labels:xval,
    datasets: [{
      // label: "Ex chart",
      data: scatterData,
      fill: false,
      showLine: true,
    }]
  };
  let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: `scatter`,
    data: toPlot,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      plugins: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Chart.js Line Chart'
        },
      },
      interaction: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: false
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          display: true,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Month'
          },
          min: 0,
          max: 5,
        },
        y: {
          display: true,
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Value'
          },
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
        }
      }
    },
  })
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think it's good approach. You can do it with canvasjs.